# How to enable Debug options in tv box with android 4.2.2?

Tags: android, adb, android-debug, android-tv

I have the TV BOX with Android 4.2.2. I need it to develop TV app. But my device doesn't have "Debug options" in settings. I tried to tap the "Build number" field (and all another fields in the "about" tab), it doesn't take effect. Also my computer didn't found any new device, when I plug my tv box by using USB. Can I do something to solve my problem?

Comment: You need to tap on it 7 times, if you didn't do that. Also, what sort of set box is this? Some hardware might run their own version of android which could be different.

Comment: Of course I tried it. I can't find the official page of my device. It is chinese brand.

Answer (score 1):

You can install "usb debug"app from google play (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.tennkia.apr)

This app can open usb setting page.

Good luck

Comment: Thanks! I already get another tv box with developer options, so I can't check your solution...

Comment: I couldn't install this app to my Android TV. I get an error "There is a Problem Parsing the Package". Note I don't have Play Store and had to download it from some apk mirror.

Comment: Hi @Sartre Could you please let me know the TV box model having developer option?